# Injecting DbContext and ILogger into database DAL constructor, best practice

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am building a Web API in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework.

My database context is registered as a service in the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<LocalDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builderLocal.ConnectionString);
});
```

And I am retrieving the `DbContext` in my controller using DI, passing it into my database-access-class (DAL) when I instantiate it for each method

```
private readonly LocalDbContext _context;

public HomeController(LocalDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public IActionResult GetSomeData(int id)
{
    var localDb = new LocalDb(_context);
    return Ok(localDb.GetSomeDataById(id));
}
```

And then my Database file:

```
public class LocalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public LocalDbContext(DbContextOptions<LocalDbContext> options)
        : base (options) { }

    **DbSets for my models**
}

public class LocalDb
{
    private readonly LocalDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<LocalDb> _logger;

    // I would want to avoid having to pass in logger in this contstructor
    public LocalDb(LocalDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
        // Can I retrieve a logger from somewhere else? From the context?
        // _logger = logger; 
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        _context.Student.Add(student);
        try
        {
          _context.SaveChanges();  
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("logMessage about exception: " + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So I wish to have the _logger available to write to, but in my code I have not set the _logger to anything. I know `ILogger` exists in the DbContext, and there is lots of guides explaining how to add and configure the logger for the Context and EF. But when I want to use my `LocalDb` class, do I have to pass in a ILogger instance for every time i call `var localDb = new LocalDb(_context, _logger)`

I feel like having to pass in a logger instance every time is a bit strange, there must be a better solution to this. Would it be possible to add the LocalDb class as a service, then dependency inject context and logger into that class? Whats the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that `HomeController` doesn't use `LocalDbContext` directly, but only uses it to pass it on to its *real* dependency, `LocalDb`. Therefore, you should not inject `LocalDbContext` into `HomeController`'s constructor, but instead inject `LocalDb` directly. This solves your problems elegantly, because now `LocalDb` can be registered in the DI Container, and it can resolve it for you with any dependency it might have.

Here's an example of a `HomeController` that depends on `LocalDb` directly.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly LocalDb _db;

    public HomeController(LocalDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult GetSomeData(int id)
    {
        return Ok(_db.GetSomeDataById(id));
    }
}
```

Because `LocalDb` is injected into the constructor, it must be registered in the DI Container:

```cs
services.AddTransient<LocalDb>();
services.AddDbContext<LocalDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builderLocal.ConnectionString);
});
```

But since `LocalDb` is composed by the DI Container, it can be extended with any dependencies, such as the `ILogger` dependency:

```cs
public class LocalDb
{
    private readonly LocalDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<LocalDb> _logger;

    public LocalDb(LocalDbContext context, ILogger<LocalDb> _logger) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger; 
    }
    ...
}
```

**TIP:** Prevent sprinkeling `catch` statements across your code base that log and rethrow. Prefer instead to have some global infrastructure that logs any requests that have failed. If I'm not mistaken ASP.NET Core does this for you out of the box. If not, this can be enabled with just a few lines of code. This makes code (such as your `LocalDb.AddStudent` much simpler, and limits the number of dependencies that a class has.

Comment: Thank you, this was the confirming answer I was looking for!

Comment: One thing to remember with DI: It's dependencies all the way down. Dependency Graphs can become quite deep and that's normal and expected. This lowers the complexity of individual classes in your application.

Comment: Ran into a challenge: My UnitTesting class is using the old constructor to inject a mock-set as the context. How can I now inject mock-sets into the database file while its expecting a `ILogger` aswell? Pass in null as the parameter and do checks in the database class?

Comment: Try hiding your `LocalDb` behind an abstraction and let the controller depend on that abstraction. This simplifies testing because the controller no longer depends on a concrete type.